# How to apply css border around text

Tags: java, html, css, image, browser

[image]

I am using http://code.google.com/p/java-html2image/ to convert HTML to image. 
How to apply border around text ?
In browser, HTML works fine and we can see the border (plz see snapshot).
With current approach HTML2Image API is not able to apply border when HTML becomes image.
Or is there any trick to apply border when HTML converted into image ?

Comment: Do you want the border to stay when it's converted into an image (i.e. the border within the image.), or do you want the image to have an html border around it?

Comment: I need exact image with upper and right border the way HTML is shown in above snapshot.

Answer (score 3):

Surround your image with a `<div>` and assign it a border.

`<div style="border:solid 2px red">
<img src="/sourceToYourImage>
</div>`

Comment: I am not using any physical image file. So '<img src' is of no use. Java API is [here](http://code.google.com/p/java-html2image/). What we see in browser, rendered by HTML code, that, I want to convert into an image. I need exact image with upper and right border the way HTML is shown in above snapshot. Answer given by [james_fuller](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21024516/1115584) is somewhat near to my question. But still that trick doesn't help me

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the HTML2Image API parses the inline CSS only.  Try putting the styles inline in the HTML to have the API pick them up.

Comment: Have you looked into the Issues tab of the project? [HTML2Image API Issues](https://code.google.com/p/java-html2image/issues/list) There are a number of issues related to formatting and CSS.  Perhaps this should be reported to the project.